# Add to Campaign not showing on report

Tags: reporting, campaign

We have a custom object called Application that is a child of the Contact.  When we build a report type linking the Contact to the Application object and then generate a report from that report type, the option to 'Add to Campaign' does not show up as an option.  We thought that since the Contact was the primary table, we would be ok.  Is there something that we are missing?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Add to Campaign button is not available on custom report types. Through the lookup or master-detail relationship, you should get a standard report type for Contacts with Applications that has an Add to Campaign button.

Here is a link to the IdeaExchange to vote up this idea:
[Campaigns: 'add to campaign' button not available in Custom Report Type](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Brk9AAC)